# How to loop on an android View to add a text from database?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Hi I am new to Android and Firebase. I am trying to loop through the TextViews and updating the values from the database.

[image: Data tree containing a root branch labeled "BCT4A" and eight children with numeric names and the value 0]

I got a simple database and would like to display all the keys (eg 71001) on multiple textviews.
I got my views instantiated as below:

```
// Instantiate Views for Rolls:
mRoll1 = findViewById(R.id.rollno1);
mRoll2 = findViewById(R.id.rollno2);
mRoll3 = findViewById(R.id.rollno3);
mRoll4 = findViewById(R.id.rollno4);
mRoll5 = findViewById(R.id.rollno5);
mRoll6 = findViewById(R.id.rollno6);
mRoll7 = findViewById(R.id.rollno7);
mRoll8 = findViewById(R.id.rollno8);
```

This will only put the last number in the text view

```
// Read from the database
mRootReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent (new ValueEventListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { 
            mRolll.setText(snapshot.getKey());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { 
        //Failed to read value
    }
});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it looks like right now is that you end up with just having `71008` in your first `TextView` because you loop through the `keys` but only ever access the first `TextView`.

If you know that you'll always have eight keys, in your case you can try adding them to your `TextViews` without the loop, something along the lines of:

```
// Read from the database
mRootReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent (new ValueEventListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        Iterator<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator(); 

        mRolll.setText(children.next().getKey());
        mRoll2.setText(children.next().getKey());
        mRoll3.setText(children.next().getKey());
        mRoll4.setText(children.next().getKey());
        mRoll5.setText(children.next().getKey());
        mRoll6.setText(children.next().getKey());
        mRoll7.setText(children.next().getKey());
        mRoll8.setText(children.next().getKey());
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { 
        //Failed to read value
    }
});
```

If you want to use a loop, I would recommend placing your `TextViews` in an `Array` or `List` and then looping through those with the children:

```
// Read from the database
mRootReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent (new ValueEventListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        Iterator<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator(); 

        TextView[] views = new TextView[] {
            mRolll,
            mRoll2,
            mRoll3,
            mRoll4,
            mRoll5,
            mRoll6,
            mRoll7,
            mRoll8,
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < views.length && children.hasNext(); i++) {
            views[i].setText(children.next().getKey());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { 
        //Failed to read value
    }
});
```

(The `Array` could be created elsewhere, probably in the same place you instantiate your `Views`)

Comment: Thanks but what if there are large number of keys. Is there a way to loop through them?

Comment: @Chautari I updated the answer to include a way to loop through them